# How to capture sound from microphone with java sound API?

Tags: java, audio, capture, microphone, javasound

The tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html 
does not cover how to select microphone.

I am enumerating mixers with the following code

```
System.out.println("Searching for microphones");
for(Mixer.Info mixerinfo : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) {
    mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerinfo); 

    //System.out.println(mixerinfo.toString());
    if( mixer.isLineSupported(Port.Info.MICROPHONE) ) {
        mixers.add(mixer);
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(mixers.size()) + ": " + mixerinfo.toString());
    }
}
```

i.e. by presense of microphone input. But next, having a mixer, I can't get line to read.

If I use `mixer.getTargetLineInfo()`, I receive an array of one `Info`, which when passing to `mixer.getLine` returns an object of type `com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer$PortMixerPort`, which is not ducumented.

If I use `mixer.getTargetLines()` I get an empty array.

If I create my own `DataLine.Info` and pass it to the mixer's `getLine`, I get unsupported exception.

So, what to do?

Comment: Check out the source I posted on [JavaSound mixer with both Port(s) and DataLine(s)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304001/javasound-mixer-with-both-ports-and-datalines/5337619#5337619) for similar source intended to explore Java Sound.

Comment: Are you analyzing names? Will it work with multilingual? I have garbage in most names.

Comment: Never tried it under locales that were not English.  Your report is worrying.

Comment: Even if it was no garbage, how one would be able to know how the word "microphone" is translated into hundreds of languages? The creators of Java Sound API were to provide logical way to find appropriate line.

Comment: Have you succeed? Can you post the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Left-field suggestion.

Provide a visual rendering of each sound line, in a component along the lines of the [AudioPlotPanel](http://pscode.org/javadoc/src-html/org/pscode/ui/audiotrace/AudioPlotPanel.html#line.49) or a simpler [RMS volume](http://pscode.org/javadoc/src-html/org/pscode/ui/audiotrace/AudioPlotPanel.html#line.913).  It should not take the user too long to figure which sound line they are yodeling through. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing. I haven't quite found a good solution yet but I can tell you that's not working out because you're trying to get a DataLine from a Port mixer. If and when I figure it out I'll be sure to let you know.