# Java Sound locale support

Tags: java, audio, locale, javasound

Does Java Sound report device names in Windows using the system language? E.g., would 'Built-in Microphone' be reported in the local language equivalent?

(I've got Windows 7 Home running in Parallels and just discovered you can't install additional languages in this version.)

Answer (score 1):

> Does Java Sound report device names in Windows using the system language?

Feedback in the comments of [How to capture sound from microphone with java sound API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261094) suggest, no.